# Find the intersection of the matches with tolerances for 2 variables in 2 dataframes in R

Tags: r, match

I want to find the intersection of the matches with tolerances (Targets$Peptide.mz * 0.001, Peaks$Peptide.mz * 0.001) for 2 variables ("Peptide.mz", "Fragment.mz") in 2 dataframes (Peaks, Targets) in R. Example is the following:

```
head(Peaks)

  Peptide.mz Fragment.mz Fragment.Intensity
1   493.2223    300.1186           337.3030
2   493.2223    300.1552           242.9032
3   493.2223    302.1497          6117.2886
4   493.2223    303.1449           761.4173
5   493.2223    304.1289          3185.0007
6   493.2223    304.1652           773.5249

head(Targets)

  Peptide.mz Fragment.mz  Sequence Fragment Rank Label
1   493.2223    774.3417 GGPFSDSYR       y6    2 light
2   493.2227    627.2733 GGPFSDSYR       y5    1 light
3   493.2223    540.2413 GGPFSDSYR       y4    5 light
4   493.2224    302.1450 GGPFSDSYR       y3    4 light
5   493.2223    436.2009 GGPFSDSYR       y7    3 light
6   498.2265    784.3500 GGPFSDSYR       y6    2 heavy
```

expected result

```
 Peptide.mz.x Fragment.mz-x  Sequence Fragment Rank Label  Peptide.mz.y Fragment.mz.y Fragment.Intensity
       493.2224    302.1450 GGPFSDSYR       y3    4 light  493.2223    302.1497          6117.2886
```

I am not very experienced in R and have no idea how to do this. Any suggestions would be highly welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

I am definitely not an expert at `data.table` but thought there might be a possibility here. I'm hoping someone might post a better alternative (but just in case, here is something to consider).

`foverlaps` with `data.table` package is great for looking at overlaps between ranges, though in your case you are checking two different columns for overlaps between two different data frames. I'm not aware of how to do this with a single `foverlaps` call. However, you could do two separate calls, and then merge the results.

Here is my example. Would start by setting minimum and maximum columns for both peptide and fragment. Then you can use `setkey` and `foverlaps` to identify overlaps, first by fragment, then by peptide. Finally, the merge where overlap exists from both results.

I created a unique ID in both `Peaks` and `Targets` to check if this worked as intended (and left in, though removed other columns like min and max).

```
library(data.table)

tolerance = .001

setDT(Peaks)
setDT(Targets)

Peaks[ , `:=`(minP = Peptide.mz - (Peptide.mz * tolerance),
              maxP = Peptide.mz + (Peptide.mz * tolerance),
              minF = Fragment.mz - (Fragment.mz * tolerance),
              maxF = Fragment.mz + (Fragment.mz * tolerance),
              PID = .I)]

Targets[ , `:=`(minP = Peptide.mz - (Peptide.mz * tolerance),
                maxP = Peptide.mz + (Peptide.mz * tolerance),
                minF = Fragment.mz - (Fragment.mz * tolerance),
                maxF = Fragment.mz + (Fragment.mz * tolerance),
                TID = .I)]

setkey(Peaks, minF, maxF)
setkey(Targets, minF, maxF)

result1 <- foverlaps(Peaks, Targets, nomatch = 0L)

setkey(Peaks, minP, maxP)
setkey(Targets, minP, maxP)

result2 <- foverlaps(Peaks, Targets, nomatch = 0L)

merge(result1, result2, by = c("PID", "TID"))[ , .SD, .SDcols = !patterns("^(min|max|i\\.)")]
```

**Output**

```
   PID TID Peptide.mz.x Fragment.mz.x Sequence.x Fragment.x Rank.x Label.x Fragment.Intensity.x Peptide.mz.y Fragment.mz.y Sequence.y Fragment.y Rank.y
1:   3   4     493.2224       302.145  GGPFSDSYR         y3      4   light             6117.289     493.2224       302.145  GGPFSDSYR         y3      4
   Label.y Fragment.Intensity.y
1:   light             6117.289
```